# How to Add Time Count Down in Auction Ads?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Countdown to a specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567241/countdown-to-a-specific-date)

How can we add a Jquery reverse time countdown which starts from Ads post day and ends with expired date?

Comment: You can't! You do that sort of thing on the serverside.

Comment: Maybe a link to this "Jquery reverse time countdown". What have you tried?

Comment: There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785029/jquery-countdown-timer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Countdown to a specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567241/countdown-to-a-specific-date)

Or try this plugin: [Countdown](http://zackperdue.com/plugins/jquery-countdown-timer), [**Demo**](http://comingsoon.thisisepic.com/)